# error:apache service not started [-1]

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed `xampp`. When i open `xampp` control panel, mysql and filezilla services are running, but not apache. When i click to start apache it gives me this

> ERROR:error:apache service not started [-1]

I have even blocked firewalls for this.

Why this is happeneing and how can i start apache services.I have installed xampp in my `E:` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many causes.

Make sure you have no other applications using the port that apache is using. From the XAMPP control panel there is a button you can press to run a tool to check which ports are in use. Applications which I know to conflict with Apache are Skype and Panda Media; there could be others.

Comment: @ Extrakun now i first clicked apache_start.bat in xampp directory.Then i typed 127.0.0.1 in url of browser.The xampp page is displayed.But i dont think apache service is started.Is it so??

Comment: i unchecked svc box for apache and apache services started running!! How is that possible? !

Answer (score 3):

here is the steps which will make apache work normally without such errors

1. Firstly, make sure that Apache is stopped
2. Make sure, Svc check box is unchecked
3. Now! go to your XAMPP Folder (`C:\xampp\apache\` – I installed the xampp in C:)
4. Now! double click on “`apache_uninstallservice.bat`” which is available in apache folder.
5. After above step, now open your XAMPP Control Panel again and click on Start button which is beside Apache, and make sure that you will not check the Svc checkbox provided.

such errors my happen in old operation systems for example win XP or Vista...
and the latest versions of xampp may not have the corresponding configurations

Answer (score 2):

I found this page looking for a solution to this problem after downloading xampp lite.

I solved this as follow:

The installed service for apache from xampp uses the standalone installation path for apache; `c:\program files\apache2.x\...etc` and not the local path in xampp folder.
Just modify all registry keys that include the wrong path for apache service in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Apache2.x` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Unselect the Svc box in the XAMPP control panel and try to restart it. Should work.